# Send email to many adressees using PHPmailer

Tags: php, html

I am making a site when I could send message to multiple email accounts. My HTML looks like that:

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
      <head>

        <title>Saada</title>
      </head>
      <form action="test1.php" method="POST">
      <body>
        <header>Küsitluse pealkiri</header>
          <br>
        <ol>
        <li>testb@localhost <input type="button" value="X"><br> <br>
        </ol>

        <input ><input type="button" value="Lisa adressaat"> <br> <br>Tekst adressaadile:<br>

        <textarea rows='4' name='tekst'></textarea>

        <br><footer>


        <INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Saada" NAME="Saada">
        </form>

        <FORM METHOD="LINK" ACTION="Minu küsitlused.html">
        <INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Loobu">


        </footer> 
      </body>
    </html>
```

And my PHP code is following (I am using PHPMailer):

```
<?php
include_once 'init/init.funcs.php';
require 'C:/xampp2/htdocs/Praks/phpmailertesting/PHPMailer_5.2.4/class.phpmailer.php';

$body = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tekst']);
$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->IsSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'localhost';  // Specify main and backup server
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'testa@localhost';                            // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'gggggg';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted

$mail->From = 'testa@localhost';
$mail->FromName = 'Indrek';
$mail->AddAddress('testb@localhost');               // Name is optional

$mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // Set word wrap to 50 characters
$mail->AddAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
$mail->AddAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
$mail->IsHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = $body;
$mail->AltBody = $body;

if(!$mail->Send()) {
   echo 'Message could not be sent.';
   echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}

echo 'Message has been sent';
?>
```

I have made it work to some extent. The message I insert into text field will be sent to email address defined in my PHP code. In this case it is `testb@localhost` (`$mail->AddAddress('testb@localhost');`). What I want to do now is that when I insert new email address into smaller textbox on my HTML site and click on submit button called **Lisa adressaat** the email will appear in list above (where right now is `testb@localhost`) and when i click on **Saada** the email will be delivered to all email addresses which are in the list. What should I add to my code to achieve this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Simply separate multiple emails with comma. It will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get all the emailaddresses and store them in an array. Once they are in the array it's just a matter of looping over all of them.

```
$mailaddresses; //this is the array with the emailadresses, store the emailaddresses here
foreach($mailaddresses as $mailaddress)
{
    $mail->AddAddress($mailaddress);
}
```

EDIT: getting the emailaddresses from an inputfield, where the emailaddresses are separated by a comma.

In the html:

```
<input type="text" value="" name="mail">
```

In the php file:

```
$mailaddresses = explode(',', str_replace(' ', '', $_POST['mail']));
//the foreach loop goes here
```

Additional info: `str_replace` is to get rid of spaces that are maybe inserted after or before the comma. `explode` splits the string where ever a comma is placed and returns them as an array of values.

Comment: Thanks, but how I insert them into an array. Sorry, I am beginner.

Comment: How are you posting the emailaddresses? Is it an input field and are you separating them with a comma or ...?

Comment: Yes it is a textfield and I am seperating them with comma.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a foreach statement

```
$emails_sent = array();

foreach ($emails as $key => $value) {
    $mail->AddAddress($value, $value);
    $emails_sent[$value] = (int) $mail->Send();
    $mail->ClearAddresses();
}
```

$emails will be the list of your emails