# How to make a group email in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, phpmailer

im using php mailer to send email in php.I just want to know if there is a way how to make a group emails in php or mysql?

i want to use that group email to send to all of my contacts.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing that comes up to mind is to just use the mail function loading the $to from an array containing all of your contacts' email adresses. It should be easy enough.

Also, you can send multiple emails just changing the parameter $to accordingly, like you can see from the example here

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Check example N° 4.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using PHPMailer:

Store all the emailaddresses you want to send an email to in an array. After that you loop over all the emailaddresses.

```
$mailaddresses; //this is the array with the emailadresses, store the emailaddresses here
foreach($mailaddresses as $mailaddress) 
{
    $mail->AddAddress($mailaddress);
}
```

I think your question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22934646/send-email-to-many-adressees-using-phpmailer/22934845#22934845)